# Cooldown is not working [Minecraft Bukkit plugin]

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

so I got a problem with the cooldown in my command. The command work perfectly but when I try to put a cooldown, it's not working. In the chat this error message is send: An internal error occurred while attempting to perform this command. In the console, it's say that:

```
    > [14:50:33 INFO]: EvilestVirus7 issued server command: /rtpPlayer
> [14:50:33 ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'rtpplayer' in plugin RandomTP v1.0
at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) ~[spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:641) ~[spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1162) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.chat(PlayerConnection.java:1078) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.entity.CraftPlayer.chat(CraftPlayer.java:237) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at can.evilestvirus.randomtp.MenuHandler.onMenuClick(MenuHandler.java:20) [RandomTpPlugin.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1630) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInWindowClick.a(SourceFile:31) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInWindowClick.a(SourceFile:9) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_212]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_212]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:44) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:715) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at can.evilestvirus.randomtp.CooldownManager.checkCooldowns(CooldownManager.java:26) ~[?:?]
at can.evilestvirus.randomtp.CommandRtpPlayer.onCommand(CommandRtpPlayer.java:22) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
... 26 more
```

This is my main class:

```
package can.evilestvirus.randomtp;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getCommand("rtpplayer").setExecutor(new CommandRtpPlayer());
        getCommand("rtp").setExecutor(new CommandRtp());
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MenuHandler(), this);
    }
}
```

There the cooldownManager class:

```
package can.evilestvirus.randomtp;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CooldownManager {

    public static HashMap<UUID, Double> cooldowns;

    public static void setupCooldown(){
        cooldowns = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static void setCooldowns(Player player, int secondes){
        double delay = System.currentTimeMillis() + (secondes * 1000);
        cooldowns.put(player.getUniqueId(), delay);

    }

    public static int getCooldowns(Player player){
        return Math.toIntExact(Math.round((cooldowns.get(player.getUniqueId()) - System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)));
    }

    public static boolean checkCooldowns(Player player){
        if(!cooldowns.containsKey(player.getUniqueId()) || cooldowns.get(player.getUniqueId()) <= System.currentTimeMillis()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the command class:

```
    package can.evilestvirus.randomtp;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;


import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;

public class CommandRtpPlayer implements CommandExecutor {


    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            if(CooldownManager.checkCooldowns(player.getPlayer())){
                CooldownManager.setCooldowns(player.getPlayer(), 10);


                Location rtp, rtp2, rtp3, rtp4, rtp5;

                Random random = new Random();
                int nbrandom = (int) (Math.random() * 4.0D) + 1;
                switch (nbrandom) {
                    case 1:
                        rtp = new Location(player.getWorld(), random.nextInt(2500), 90.0D,
                                random.nextInt(2500), 1.8F, 7.4F);
                        player.teleport(rtp);
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION, 200, 99));
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.DAMAGE_RESISTANCE, 200, 99));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        rtp2 = new Location(player.getWorld(), -random.nextInt(2500), 90.0D,
                                -random.nextInt(2500), 1.8F, 7.4F);
                        player.teleport(rtp2);
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION, 200, 99));
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.DAMAGE_RESISTANCE, 200, 99));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        rtp3 = new Location(player.getWorld(), -random.nextInt(2500), 90.0D,
                                random.nextInt(2500), 1.8F, 7.4F);
                        player.teleport(rtp3);
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION, 200, 99));
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.DAMAGE_RESISTANCE, 200, 99));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        rtp4 = new Location(player.getWorld(), random.nextInt(2500), 90.0D,
                                -random.nextInt(2500), 1.8F, 7.4F);
                        player.teleport(rtp4);
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION, 200, 99));
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.DAMAGE_RESISTANCE, 200, 99));
                        break;
                    default:
                        rtp5 = new Location(player.getWorld(), random.nextInt(2500), 90.0D,
                                -random.nextInt(2500), 1.8F, 7.4F);
                        player.teleport(rtp5);
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION, 200, 99));
                        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.DAMAGE_RESISTANCE, 200, 99));
                        break;
                }
                player.sendMessage("§a§lVous venez d'être téléporté aléatoirement!");
            }else{
                player.getPlayer().sendMessage("Vous pourez utiliser la commandes dans " + CooldownManager.getCooldowns(player.getPlayer()) + " seconds");
            }

            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never run the `setupCooldowns()` method you have inside your `CooldownManager` class. I would recommend you remove this method anyways and simply instantiate the cooldown using `Map<UUID, Double> cooldowns = new HashMap<>();`

The reason you’re getting a NullPointerException is because your HashMap has not been instantiated (does not exist)

Comment: Okay, so I've done what you said, and it's work! The only thing, is that when I try to redo the command, it's block me because the cooldown is not finish but it's does not show me the message and it's say "An internal error occurred while attempting to perform this command." In the console, there the log error: Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow

Comment: @nat.laliberte that happens because you are performing an arithmetic equation between a double and an int

Comment: but if you implement more "setup" logic, I would put them into an constructor